# Windows store not installing or updating apps

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-store-app

For months now, I've had a number of "Downloads and updates" in the Windows Store that kept saying "Starting download..." but never actually did anything.

Today, I went through a number of online solutions, including:

1. Running WSReset (this didn't do anything, it just showed a black window for 15+ minutes).
2. Signing out and back into the Windows Store
3. Resetting the Windows Store app

None of this seems to have helped. I no longer have anything in my "Downloads and updates", but I still can't install any apps.

For example, when I try to install Messenger, after I click Install on the screen below, it does nothing:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOF04.png

If I *do* try to click "Get updates" in the "Downloads and updates" section, it shows a spinner forever:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYCHb.png

What should I do?

Comment: Do you have UAC (User Account Control) turned OFF?  Store needs UAC ON.   Try running DISM and restarting after.  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth

Comment: If you used any software that claimed to disable spying on Windows 10 you will have to reinstall Windows.  Incorrect permissions on WindowsApps can prevent the installation of new UWP applications.  If you are running 1909 and your machine doesn’t have any of the hardware listed in the known problems for 2004 upgrading to 2004 is a easy viable solution to problems like this.  However, permissions changes or undocumented tweaks to your system, can prevent the upgrade from being successful

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't install any software like that

Comment: @John UAC is on

Comment: @user9846951 - The behavior still indicates an underline problem, in-place repair or upgrade to the next version, seems like your best bet

Comment: I agree that a Repair Install is the next thing to try. Media Creation Link and consider upgrade if your hardware and drivers are up to date and otherwise the second link (install)

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the latest Windows version seems to have fixed it.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10